# For a Generic outerclass, why do i need to declare the nested class static?

Tags: java, generics, nested-class

I am trying to write the Data Structure for a Hash Table using Chaining. When i remove the keyword "static" from the nested class, i get the error that "Cannot create a generic array of SeparateChaining.Node"? on the line where i allocate memory to hmap using new.

With the static keyword it works fine.Can anybody please point out the significance of the keyword static here and the difference it makes? I am creating an array of object, then how come it shows generic array in the error (Eclipse)?

```
public class SeparateChaining<Key,Value> {

    private int m;

    private Node[] hmap;

    private int n;

    public SeparateChaining()
    {
        m=5;
        n=0;

        //error here on removal of static keyword from the node  class declaration
                hmap=new Node[m];

    }

    private ____ class Node //works fine with static. Otherwise shows error
    {
        private Object key;
        private Object value;
        private Node next;

        public Node(Object k, Object v)
        {

            key=k;
            value=v;
        }

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the type of `key` be `Key` and the type of `value` be `Value` (not `Object`)? And the same for the constructor parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you declare the inner `Node` class as `static`, then the class is associated with the outer class `SeparateChaining`. `Node` is then in fact `SeparateChaining.Node`.

Without the `static`, it will be associated with an instance of `SeparateChaining`, which will need a couple type parameters, thus the inner `Node` class will also need those type parameters. `Node` is then in fact `SeparateChaining<Key, Value>.Node`; and in Java, [creating an array of generics](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse332/10sp/otherNotes/genericArrays.html) is not legal.

Comment: Adding to the above it works if you try and construct Node<Key,Value>

Comment: @Dukeling That would change the meaning of the program a little bit, am I right?

Comment: In that case, the type parameter of Node will  be not the same as the type parameter of the outer `SeparateChaining`; it will shadow that value, instead of using it.

Comment: Adding to the above, it works (compiles) if you try to construct the array as `new SeparateChaining.Node[m]`.

Comment: @Indoknight Do you mean constructing the array as `new Node<Key,Value>[m]`? This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is generic. If the inner class is not static then the type is `SeparateChaining<Key,Value>.Node`. When you add static then it's treated like a regular class

Answer (score -1):

Keyowrd `static` in the declaration of the nested class means "I don't want to have a reference to an object of the outer class, thank you very much". If you don't put `static`, then any object of the inner class has a reference to some object of the outer class.

And thus an object of inner, non-static class can be created only inside a non-static method of an object of the outer class.